# Drill down in ssrs based on column values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

[image][image][image]I need to make a drill down report based on column values. I have already created report but I need to implement drill down in my report.

My column values are like below based on which I need to drill down my report.
`Top Line Income, Products (GL), NII, NIR, Products (Non-GL), NIIT, NIRT, WIP, No.Of Prospect NII, No.Of prospect NT`

and so on....

Now I have to implement a drill down such that If I click on Top line income,`Products (GL)`, `NII`, `NRR`,`Products (Non-GL)`, `NIIT` and `NIRT` should expand.
And If I click `WIP`, `No.Of Prospect NII` and `No.Of prospect NT` should expand. Basically, the SSRS report should be structured like:

```
+Top Line income,
+WIP,
```

Here column 'Measure_code' has all the above values like Top line income,Products (GL), NII, NIR, Products (Non-GL), NIIT, NIRT, WIP, No.Of Prospect NII, No.Of prospect NT and so on...

We have calculated measures (ex. sum(actual), sum(Target) etc.) as well in front of all Measure code column values.

Could you please help me out how to achieve this, As I am very new to SSRS.

Comment: Can you share the query of your dataset and maybe a printscreen of your  report so far?

Comment: Hi Nicky, Thanks for your reply. Below is the data set Query. Here Measure_code has all the above values like Products (GL), NII, NIR, Products (Non-GL), NIIT, NIRT, WIP, No.Of Prospect NII, No.Of prospect NT and so on.....Here Query I have give in parts because I was not able to copy in one shot.

Comment: WITH

MEMBER [Measures].[Measure_Key] AS [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].MEMBER_KEY
MEMBER [Measures].[Measure_Group_Key] AS [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].PARENT.MEMBER_KEY
MEMBER [Measures].[Structure_Level] AS [CustomerStructure].[Provincial Structure].LEVEL_NUMBER

SET [ReportLevel] 
AS FILTER([Report Levels].[Report Level].[Report Level], 
 CINT([Report Levels].[Report Level].Properties( "Structure Level" )) = CINT([Measures].[Structure_Level]))

MEMBER [Measures].[Sequence] AS [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties( "Sequence" )

Comment: MEMBER [Measures].[Indent] AS [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties( "Font Indent" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Weight] AS [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties( "Font Weight" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Header] AS [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties( "Values Header" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Header1Caption] AS [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties( "Header Name1" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Header2Caption] AS [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties( "Header Name2" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Header3Caption] AS [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties( "Header Name3" )

Comment: MEMBER [Measures].[Actual] AS [Measures].[Measure Value]
MEMBER [Measures].[Target] AS [Measures].[Measure Target]
MEMBER [Measures].[Average] AS [Measures].[Average Value]

SELECT
{
 [Measures].[Measure_Key],
 [Measures].[Measure_Group_Key],
 [Measures].[Structure_Level],
 [Measures].[Sequence],
 [Measures].[Indent],
 [Measures].[Weight],
 [Measures].[Header],
 [Measures].[Header1Caption],
 [Measures].[Header2Caption],
 [Measures].[Header3Caption],
 [Measures].[Actual],
 [Measures].[Target],
 [Measures].[Average]
} ON COLUMNS,

Comment: {
 FILTER(
  [ReportLevel] *
  ORDER(
   DESCENDANTS(STRTOMEMBER(@Financial_Measure),
   [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].[Measure Code], LEAVES),
   [Measures].[Sequence], ASC),
  [Measures].[Active Indicator] <> 0)
} ON ROWS
FROM
 [ScoreCard]
WHERE
 (STRTOMEMBER(@SiteStructure), STRTOMEMBER(@Time))